# creating movie template "on the fly"

Tags: rendering, web-frameworks

i want to develop a site where user selects various videos and site will render a single video containing all videos in a pre-built template.

what would be the way to go about this (in order to create the movie dynamically from site) ?
what would be the server side framework to use ?

can i use after-effects and have site use it to generate such templates (optional - as i have a friend who works with after effects and can create templates) ?

as i am fairly new to the field any additional information is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure you can't do what you described.

Rendering a video consumes huge resources (really huge), so a server park that could
 handle this is just not worth it. 
 However, what you can do is to play the selected videos consecutively. That way, no rendering is necessary.

Also, forget about After Effects, for the same reasons described above.

Comment: there are sites that already do this, any solution would be welcomed such as flash based templates and so on. an example site that does this is [magisto](http://www.magisto.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using a new plugin for After Effects called [Templater Bot](http://dcly.io/templater-bot-aes).  From [Dataclay's site](http://dataclay.com):

Templater Bot is an enterprise solution for custom video on demand. It works as an automated system. Use it to periodically check for incoming data, pull new data in, and render video as a background process. Or use the command line interface to push data in to create new renders. Once your AE project is prepared, use Bot to customize and render it without operating the After Effects user interface. Developers can create front end applications, such as web or mobile apps, that feed data into Templater's data source, offering a collaborative, custom video content creation solution.